# Using PHPMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench, how to search across 10 tables and return all records matching a specific criteria?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This seems like it should be so simple but I'm having a hell of a time solving it.

I have 10 tables named in the following way:

```
b1_settings
b2_settings
...
b10_settings
```

I need to search across all of them, and return one specific field for all records with `weight=0`.  Basically I want to do this (which is of course invalid):

```
select title from *_settings where weight=0
```

Is there any way to accomplish this using PHPMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench (I have to avoid command line solutions in this instance) without a huge ugly query that specified each and every table individually?

Comment: i'm not sure i follow your restrictions, when you say command line, what exactly does that mean? because i'm sure php can handle this task easily.

Comment: Yes PHP can handle this, I'm saying that this must be accomplished within the environments of either PHPMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench.  No writing a separate script to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i'm pretty sure this is what you're looking for in `phpmyadmin SEARCH` click on the +Option button at the bottom of the search page.

[image]

In the Search Condition section, Is where you can enter command like searches. In your situation, you can do a search like for something like `Sickest`, it would look something like this.

`'Sickest' in (b1_settings, b2_settings, b3_settings, b4_settings, b5_settings, b6_settings, b7_settings, b8_settings, b9_settings, b10_settings)`

This will go through each `bx_settings` field and locate the name `Sickest` and return your results to you.

Comment: Problem is I'm not looking for a string.  I'm looking for a condition... weight=0.  So I don't think this will work... though if I'm wrong, please comment.  Thanks!

Comment: not sure what you mean, is weight a string? is weight=0 a string? can you put this in an example

Comment: Oops, sorry I wasn't clear.  `weight` is the field name, zero is the value I'm wanting to search for.  The query to do this on just a single table would be something like `SELECT title FROM b1_settings WHERE weight=0`

Comment: i would like to see what your database actually looks like, cause i still don't have a clue what you're talking about, show me a field where it says weight=0, if you can

Comment: My table has a field called `weight`.  That field contains numeric values.  If the field is set to zero, then I want to get the value in the `title` field for that record.  Make sense now?